How to disable or redirect logs from console printed by 3rd party libraries which are using Go native zk package?
I'm building a CLI using the Cobra library in Go. According to my requirements, I need to use the zk package which is the Native ZooKeeper client for Go. The problem is that the logs from this 3rd party is getting printed on the console. I only want the logs of my own cobra application (using the fmt package) to get printed. I don't want the logs from the zk package to be displayed.
Was wondering what can be some approaches used for preventing the display of these logs.

The zk package allows you to pass a customer Logger as a connection option, like this:
type yourOwnLogger struct {}
func (yourOwnLogger) Printf(string, ...interface{}) {
    // Do what you want with the log message here
}

func main() {
    zkc := zk.Connect([]string{"127.0.0.1"}, time.Second, zk.WithLogger(yourOwnLogger{}))
}

The logger needs to implement zk.Logger, which is an interface that requires one func: Printf(string, ...interface{}).
Their default simply forwards the log to log.Printf(), but you can do whatever you want (ignore it, write it to something else, parse it, whatever you need).
